# Probability Average amount of rolls

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics, problem-solving

I have a question regarding probability. I'll start by saying I've never taken a statistics or other similar course and was trying to work out this for a game. On average how many attempts will it take to get all 24 outcomes if there is a 1/16 chance of getting an outcome and there can be duplicates of the outcome. 
My thought was 
$\sum_{i=1}^n (256/i)$ where n = 24
This would make this answer ~ 966.6 attempts. Wondering if I did this right. If not, could someone please explain the correct answer to me.

Comment: I have taken a preliminary statistics course and have never heard of such an idea before, though it is very intriguing. Also, a 1/16 chance per one of 24 outcomes makes no sense. If there are only 24 possible outcomes, and each one is balanced, then the probability is 1/24 not 1/16.

Comment: I do not understand all $24$ outcomes where there is a $1/16$ chance. If there are $24$ outcomes I would expect $1/24$. If the two numbers are indeed intended, one needs a more precise definition of the game. Does one sometimes get more than one outcome?

Comment: Unfortunately, probability is inherently random. The average probably does not exist. After all, there are many occurences with near infinite amounts of tries before the expected outcome. Maybe you need to think about balancing them somehow. For instance, if one outcome with 100000000 attempts has a probability of 0.00000005, is it weighed differently in the average then a combination of occurences with a 1/2 probability of occurring? Unfortunately, this seems like an issue of philosophy. It's not your fault but "average" just seems vague to me, and probably just does not apply.

Comment: A $1/16$ chance for each outcome? Is this a typo? If you actually meant $1/24$ then this is the Coupon Collector's Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: @AndréNicolas rereading it, I believe he means "there is a 1/16 chance of getting one desirable outcome. There are 24 desirable outcomes.". I assume there are a number x of *undesirable* outcomes, which consist the other 84%.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck This sounds like OP means average to be expectation

Comment: I explained that badly. Maybe like 24 items and you have 1/16 chance of receiving any item. So duplicates can happen.

Comment: @Captain nope. I know expected value. That is (as analogy) how much you will have after gambling for an infinite amount of time. He is asking how long it takes to get said desriable result. Tit for tat if you will. They appear to contrast each other in a weird way, IMO.

Comment: @BlakeAdam1 so my guess was correct?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Expected number of trials until success is also a well-defined concept

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: If it is indeed $1/16$ of getting something other than garbage, then the expectation is $\sum_1^{24} \frac{(16)(24)}{i}$. But for me the comment by OP does not yet clarify the intended interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to interpret your question:

> Suppose you have $24$ very biased coins so that there is a
>   $\frac{1}{16}$ probability that each shows heads when flipped.  Each
>   round you flip all the coins.  What is the expected number of rounds
>   until you have seen each coin show heads at least once?

- The probability that a particular coin has never shown heads in $n$ flips is $\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^n$
- The probability that a particular coin has shown heads at least once in  $n$ flips is $1-\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^n$
- The probability that all $24$ coins have shown heads at least once in $n$ rounds is $\left(1-\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^n\right)^{24}$
- The probability that all $24$ coins have shown heads at least once at the  $n$th round is $\left(1-\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^n\right)^{24}-\left(1-\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^{n-1}\right)^{24}$
- The expected number of rounds needed so that all $24$ coins have shown heads at least once $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n\left(\left(1-\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^n\right)^{24}-\left(1-\left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^{n-1}\right)^{24}\right) $
- This seems to be about $59.00705$

Comment: Ill try to re-explain. There are 24 unique items. The chance of getting any of the 24 is 1/16. So the chance of getting a specific one in 1/384. On average how many tries would it take to get all of the unique items. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @BlakeAdam1: If you get one (chosen uniformly at random with replacement) with probability $\frac1{16}$ and nothing with probability $\frac{15}{16}$, then the expectation is the Coupon Collectors solution multiplied by $16$ so $\displaystyle  16 \sum_{i=1}^{24} \frac{24}{i} \approx 1449.968$ much as André Nicolas says